# Caffe Python API reference?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

My main gripe about Caffe is that although there are a few examples in the documentation, there is no definitive reference guide. This applies especially to the Python interface (which would be great if there was a reference guide), and also to prototxt. It seems that in order to use Caffe properly, the user must already be an expert in Google Protobuf and CUDA. Shame to admit I have no experience in either of those things.

So how do I look up things (like function signature, supported values for various variables, and so on) in the Python interface? From [this example](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/01-learning-lenet.ipynb) we can see that we can create a data layer in Python as follows.

```
n.data, n.label = L.Data(batch_size=batch_size, backend=P.Data.LMDB, source=lmdb,
                         transform_param=dict(scale=1./255), ntop=2)
```

This is very nice, because afterwards we can export the network we made in Python to `prototxt`. The problem however, is that I have no idea how to make a slightly different data layer (with different parameters or different backends for example), and there seems to be nowhere to look these things up. How, for example, do I construct the following layer in `prototxt` using PyCaffe code?

```
layer {
  name: "image"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "image"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "./training_data_paths.txt"
    batch_size: 64
  }
}
```

Where do I look up what (Python) functions to call and what arguments they take and what are the valid values for the arguments? I've asked essentially the same question on [Caffe Users' Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/MEd2vkXsJRA) but no one answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protobuffer definition of caffe can be found at [`$CAFFE_ROOT/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto) there you can see the different parameters and their accepted value.

To create `"HDF5Data"` layer instead of a `"Data"` layer using `caffe.NetSpec()` interface, you can

```
n.image = L.HDF5Data(hdf5_data_param={'source': './training_data_paths.txt',  
                                      'batch_size': 64},
                     include={'phase': caffe.TRAIN})
```

Comment: I guess this is the closest to an API reference as we can get. It still doesn't answer a lot of questions, for example, in Python we use the class `HDF5Data` as if it's a subclass of `Data`, but where is that apparent in the `caffe.proto` file? In practice, `HDF5Data` is not subclassing `Data`, but the interface is as though it is, due to the way parameters are read from and to the proto files. But I only found that out through arduous deciphering of the source code, and life would be so much easier if there was an actual API reference.

Comment: @Ray I suppose that from python interface point of view, `HDF5Data` is **not** a subclass of `Data`...

Comment: @Shai: Good solition. However, I found that you may be missing a parameter `ntop=2`. Is it right? In addition, If I want to make train and val prototxt in a single prototxt. Could I use the code `n.data, n.label = L.HDF5Data(batch_size=batch_size, source=source_path, ntop=2, include={'phase': caffe.TRAIN})
        n.data, n.label = L.HDF5Data(batch_size=batch_size, source=source_path,ntop=2, include={'phase': caffe.TEST})`? Do I need change the variable `ndata,nlabel` in testing and training? Thanks

Comment: @user8264 if you want both data and label outputs then you need ntop=2. as for train and test phase: there's no simple solution

Comment: Thanks. It means we must be write it in individual file. This is my reference question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289880/how-can-i-generate-data-layer-hdf5-for-training-and-testing-in-same-prototxt